# Displaying error message in popup JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, error-handling, popup

How to generate popup while displaying validation error? For example for `<h:inputText required="true">` if I skip and press submit button I want to display `<h:message>` in a popup. Is that possible in JSF 2.0 or using jQuery or any other?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very much possible.

To generate the popup, use the jQuery dialog widget (documented [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)).

Place the following in your xhtml:

```
<h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}" ...>
```

This will ensure that the javascript will get rendered if there is at least one message.

In the javascript referenced by h:outputScript, load a jQuery dialog with *h:messages* as the contents. Ensure that the "autoOpen" attribute of the jQuery dialog is set to true. This will render the dialog as soon as the document loads.

Hope this helps.